# При запуске кода вылетает ошибка на 12 строке AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get' не могу решить

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string
url = input("> ")
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'})
stat = r.status_code
s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
f = s.find_all('div', 'c-card__body u-display-flex u-flex-direction-column')
href = list()
for i in s:
        j = i.find('a')
        href.append(j.get('href'))
types = s.find_all('span', 'c-meta__type')
urls = list()
for c in range(len(href)):
    urls.append(f'https://www.nature.com{href[c]}')
if len(urls) == 0:
    print("This site does not contain articles with the type of news")

saved_articles = list()
for url in urls:
    r2 = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'})
    s = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, "lxml")
    body = s.find('div', 'c-article-body u-clearfix')
    paragraphs = body.find_all('p', {'class': ''})
    title = s.title.text
    titlewp = title.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    article_name = titlewp.translate(str.maketrans(" ", "_", "—"))
    while "__" in article_name:
        article_name = article_name.replace("__", "_")

        saved_articles.append(f'{article_name}.txt')

        file = open(f'{article_name}.txt', "wb+")
        for p in paragraphs:
            file.write(bytes(p.text, 'utf8'))
        file.close()

        print(f'Saved articles: {saved_articles}')
if stat == 200:
    print("Content saved")
else:
    print("The URL returned ", stat, "!")
```

Comment: а как вы понимаете эту ошибку (о чём она говорит - что не нравится интерпретатору?) - что именно вы не можете решить относительно неё?

Comment: А зачем вы `f` считаете, а потом нигде не используете, интересно?

Comment: И посмотрите, что у вас в `i` получается и в `j`. Станет понятнее, думаю.